# How to make a Histogram where there's both stacked AND grouped bars?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to create a histogram in Excel where one bar is a stacked one (detailing some values) and the others being grouped bars (normal histogram) is this possible (straighforwardly without overlaying bars) ? if yes, thanks for detailing the steps.

I tried with customized histogram but i don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without an example of what you're trying to accomplish, I'm guessing you want something like this?

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly, how to do that in the latest Excel with the stacks being labeled ? Thanks !

Comment: Just click on each stack area and select "Add Data Label". Or add data labels to all of them and then manually remove the labels you don't want. I modified the screen shot with just labels on the stacked bar.

Comment: And how you created the chart from the table in the first place ?

Comment: Stacked has no common value1 with otehr bars as well so it is not exactly my example !

Comment: Then I would recommend providing some sample data and how it should look.